# Mongoose: build query with populated data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection with groups and user:

Group schema:

```
const groupSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    members: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
});
```

User schema:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        min: 6,
        max: 255
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        min: 5,
        max: 255
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        require: true,
        min: 6,
        max: 1024,
    },
});
```

Now, I want to build a query to find all groups, the user is part of. I tried to build it like this:

```
const userId = '...';
const groups = await Group.find({members: userId}).populate('members');
```

With this query I get an empty array, which should not be the result. How can I fix my query?

The result of the query without any filters looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "members": [
            {
                "_id": "6044c5d9b63a2a0ce0d0a32e",
                "name": "Test",
                "email": "test@test.com"
            }
        ],
        "_id": "6045e9837e66e80eca2a689c",
        "name": "Test",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

Comment: Have you tried by using the [$in operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) ? Like: `await Group.find({members: { $in: [userId] }}).populate('members');`

Comment: I just tried your suggestion, but I got the same result. I also added the result of the query without any filters, maybe this helps to find the problem.

Comment: gotcha and the result without any filters def help. You can try `await Group.find({'members._id': { $in: [userId] }}).populate('members');`

Comment: I have also tried something similar without success. However, I don't think it works because the populate() method is called after the find(), so the field '_id' does not exist at this point. Do I understand this correctly?

Comment: oh, the `populate()` is not necessary since you are embedding the member document into the `members` array.

Comment: I just figured out what my problem was. I also posted the details as an answer. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error after checking the data in the database. The problem was, that the ids in the `members` array was stored as a `String`. After changing the type to `ObjectId` the query is working fine.